# Poor AI for 2048 written in Haskell

Tags: game, haskell, ai

I'm learning Haskell and thought it would be fun to write an AI for the game [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) in Haskell.

In my implementation I got rid of the randomized aspects of the game.

This makes the program deterministic (or pure). However, I don't think it performs very well. It uses a very simple algorithm:

Recurse into all possible moves with depth `x` and return the number of empty tiles of the result. The move that results in the highest number of empty tiles is seen as the best move.

I use a 16-length List to represent the board. I am afraid that the many list operations make my program very slow, and wonder if there are better ways to solve this.

The code:

```
{--

Plays and solves the game 2048

--}
import Data.Time
import Control.Monad

emptyGrid :: [Int]
emptyGrid = [ 0 | _ <- [0..15] ]

-- Display the 16-length list as the 4 by 4 grid it represents
gridToString :: [Int] -> String
gridToString []         = ""
gridToString xs         = show (take 4 xs) ++ "\n" ++ gridToString (drop 4 xs)

printGrid :: [Int] -> IO()
printGrid xs            = putStrLn $ gridToString xs

-- Skip n empty tiles before inserting
addTile :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] 
addTile 0 (0:grid)      = 2 : grid
addTile n []            = []
addTile n (0:grid)      = (0 : addTile (n-1) grid)
addTile n (cell:grid)   = cell : addTile n grid

-- Insert multiple tiles at once
addTiles :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addTiles [] grid        = grid
addTiles (n:ns) grid    = addTiles ns (addTile n grid)

-- For one row of the grid, push the non-empty tiles together
-- e.g. [0,2,0,2] becomes [2,2,0,0]
moveRow :: [Int] -> [Int]
moveRow []                  = []
moveRow (0:xs)              = moveRow xs ++ [0]
moveRow (x:xs)              = x : moveRow xs

-- For one row of the grid, do the merge (cells of same value merge)
-- e.g. [2,2,4,4] becomes [4,8,0,0]
-- [2,4,2,2] becomes [2,4,4,0]

mergeRow :: [Int] -> [Int]
mergeRow []                 = []
mergeRow (a:[])             = [a]
mergeRow (a:b:xs)           
    | a == b                = (a + b) : (mergeRow xs) ++ [0]
    | otherwise             = a : mergeRow (b:xs)

-- Rotate the grid to be able to do vertical moving/merging
-- e.g. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
-- becomes [0,4,8,12,1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15]
rotate :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotate grid = [ grid !! (a + 4 * b) | a <- [0..3], b <- [0..3] ]

-- Use the definitions above to do the moves
move :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
move _ []               = []
-- 0=Left, 1=Right, 2=Up, 3=Down
move 0 grid             = mergeRow (moveRow (take 4 grid)) ++ move 0 (drop 4 grid) 
move 1 grid             = reverse (move 0 (reverse grid))
move 3 grid             = rotate (move 0 (rotate grid))
move 2 grid             = reverse (move 3 (reverse grid))

-- Mapping of move-codes to text
moveToString :: Int -> String
moveToString n = ["Left", "Right", "Up", "Down"] !! n

-- Take a turn, i.e. make a move and add a tile
takeTurn :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
takeTurn n grid
    | n == -1               = []
    | newGrid /= grid       = newGrid
    | otherwise             = []
    where newGrid = addTile 0 (move n grid)

maxInList :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maxInList (x:xs) = maxInList_ x xs 
maxInList_ :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> a
maxInList_ m [] = m
maxInList_ m (x:xs)     = maxInList_ (max m x) xs

-- Find highest tuple in list of pairs.
-- On equality, the first wins
maxTuple :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int
maxTuple []                 = -1
maxTuple (x:xs)             = secondFromTuple $ maxTuple_ x xs
secondFromTuple :: (a,a) -> a
secondFromTuple (x,y)       = y
maxTuple_ :: Ord a => (a,a) -> [(a,a)] -> (a,a)
maxTuple_ x []              = x
maxTuple_ (a,b) ((y,z):xs)
    | a >= y                = maxTuple_ (a,b) xs
    | otherwise             = maxTuple_ (y,z) xs

-- Return the best possible move
-- TODO: can the seemingly redundancy be eliminated?
bestMove :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
bestMove depth grid         = maxTuple [ (gridValue depth (takeTurn x grid), x) | x <- [0..2], takeTurn x grid /= [] ]

gridValue :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
gridValue _ [] = -1
gridValue 0 grid = length $ filter (==0) grid
gridValue depth grid = maxInList [ gridValue (depth-1) (takeTurn x grid) | x <- [0..2] ]

-- Take turns and prints the result of each move to the console until no more moves are possible
-- n counts the moves
-- Should normally be called with n=0
takeTurns :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO()
takeTurns depth n grid          = do
    let newGrid                 = takeTurn (bestMove depth grid) grid
    if newGrid /= []
        then do
            when (n `rem` 100 == 0) $ putStrLn $ "Move " ++ (show n)
            -- putStrLn $ "Move " ++ (show n)
            -- putStrLn $ gridToString newGrid
            takeTurns depth (n+1) newGrid
        else do
            putStrLn $ gridToString grid
            putStrLn $ "Game Over: " ++ (show n) ++ " Turns"

solve :: Int -> IO()
solve depth = takeTurns depth 0 emptyGrid

solveTenTimes :: Int -> IO()
solveTenTimes 10 = putStrLn "Done"
solveTenTimes n = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    solve n 
    stop <- getCurrentTime
    putStrLn $ (show n) ++ ": " ++ (show $ diffUTCTime stop start)
    solveTenTimes (n+1)

main = do
    solveTenTimes 0
```

**Edit**

I posted a revised version here: [Revised: AI for 2048 in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/revised-ai-for-2048-in-haskell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all - way to go! Type signatures, pattern matching, monads - you're clearly on the right track.

Some general tips:

1. Don't reinvent the wheel!

   When you encounter a function that looks like this:

   ```
   secondFromTuple :: (a,a) -> a
   secondFromTuple (x,y)       = y
   ```

   your first thought should be: "wait, that's a really simple and usefuly function. I wonder if it's already in the standard library?". Well, let's search [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for the type signature `(a,a)->a`: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%2Ca%29-%3Ea

   The first result is: `snd :: (a, b) -> b`, which is actually the right function. `snd` is even more general than `secondFromTuple` - the latter won't work on `(0,"zero")`, for example, because it's type is `(Int,String)` and `secondFromTuple` only work on homogenous tuples.

   Another example: `maximum` is a standard library function that behave just like `maxInList`. Notice that `maxInList []` will result in a pattern match failure while `maximum []` will result in an `empty list` exception.

   Now let's take a look at `maxTuple`. It takes a list of tuples and return the second item of the tuple with the highest first item. Can we replace it with a standard library function?

   Well, the `Data.List` module contains `maximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`. The `By` family of functions - `sortBy`,`nubBy` - are variation of standard function like `maximum`,`sort` and `nub`, which compares items using an external comparison function. Usually, and easy way to create one is with the `comparing` function from `Data.Ord`. For example, `comparing fst` is a function that gets 2 tuples and compares them by the first element. So `maximumBy (comparing fst)` will return the tuple with the highest first item, and `snd` will return its second item.

   So we can rewrite `maxTuple` as `maxTuple xs = snd $ maximumBy (comparing fst)`, or in pointfree style - `maxTuple = snd . maximumBy (comparing fst)`.

   There's one small issue here: One, we don't know how `maximumBy` resolves ties - if it's an issue, you can modify the solution a little, maybe use `sortBy` or write a different comparison function.
2. If you need to fail - fail

   `maxTuple []` returns `-1`, and that's not a good idea. `maxTuple [(0,-1)]` returns `-1` as well - how can you tell if it's a valid result?

   If a function encounters an invalid state - you need to report an error. There are several ways to do it - I'll mention two:

   - Throw an error: `maxTuple [] = error "maxTuple: empty list"`. It's the simplest way to do it, and in a small-scale project it's probably the best. The downside is that error-handling is an `IO` operation, so this error can't be handled in pure code.
   - The `Maybe` monad:

     ```
     maxTuple :: [(Int,Int)] -> Maybe Int
     maxTuple [] = Nothing
     maxTuple xs = Just $ snd $ maximumBy (comparing fst)
     ```

     This is the safer way to do it. A failure results in `Nothing`. The caller can then deal with this `Nothing` instead of simply crashing the program. The downside is that now you need to examine the value of `maxTuple` before using it, which complicates the code. `Data.Maybe` and `Control.Monad` can help with this task.

   You can read more about proper Haskell error handling in [this great article](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors).
3. Use `data` instead of hardcoded values

   Instead of representing directions with 0-3, you can use `data`:

   ```
   data Direction = Left | Right | Up | Down
                    deriving (Show)
   ```

   Now `move` is more readable:

   ```
   move :: Direction -> [Int] -> [Int]
   ...
   move Left grid  = ...
   move Right grid = ...
   move Down grid  = ...
   move Up grid    = ...
   ```

   Also, since there's no 5th direction, `move 4` results in a pattern match failure. In the new version, there is no such danger.

   Plus, `deriving (Show)` means we can use `show` on `Direction` value - so we get `moveToString` for free: `show Left` returns "Left", `show Down` returns "Down" and so on.

That's it for now. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'll definately be upgrading my code with your advice. You're right about using library functions... I don't really know my way in the Haskell libraries yet.

Comment: I implemented your feedback and posted a revised version of my code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/revised-ai-for-2048-in-haskell It would be great if you could take a look at it!

Comment: Well done! As for the performance issue - have you tried profiling it? GHC has some profiling tools (which I've never used myself)

Comment: You have a point!