# Revised: AI for 2048 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ai

This is a revised version of an AI for the game [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/), written in Haskell.

Link to original thread: [Poor AI for 2048 written in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46493/poor-ai-for-2048-written-in-haskell)

I think this version is a lot cleaner, thanks to the tips from Benesh.

I would like to know if I'm following best practice guidelines and especially if I made the right choices performance-wise.

I think the program is already a bit slow, and it will become a lot slower if start implementing the randomized aspects of the game.

```
{--

Plays and solves the game 2048

In this implementation the randomized aspects of the game have been removed.

--}
import Data.Time
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

emptyGrid :: [Int]
emptyGrid = [ 0 | _ <- [0..15] ]

-- Display the 16-length list as the 4 by 4 grid it represents
gridToString :: [Int] -> String
gridToString []         = ""
gridToString xs         = show (take 4 xs) ++ "\n" ++ gridToString (drop 4 xs)

printGrid :: [Int] -> IO()
printGrid xs            = putStrLn $ gridToString xs

-- Skip n empty tiles before inserting
addTile :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] 
addTile 0 (0:grid)      = 2 : grid
addTile _ []            = []
addTile n (0:grid)      = (0 : addTile (n-1) grid)
addTile n (cell:grid)   = cell : addTile n grid

-- For one row of the grid, push the non-empty tiles together
-- e.g. [0,2,0,2] becomes [2,2,0,0]
moveRow :: [Int] -> [Int]
moveRow []              = []
moveRow (0:xs)          = moveRow xs ++ [0]
moveRow (x:xs)          = x : moveRow xs

-- For one row of the grid, do the merge (cells of same value merge)
-- e.g. [2,2,4,4] becomes [4,8,0,0]
-- [2,4,2,2] becomes [2,4,4,0]

mergeRow :: [Int] -> [Int]
mergeRow []             = []
mergeRow (a:[])         = [a]
mergeRow (a:b:xs)
    | a == b            = (a + b) : (mergeRow xs) ++ [0]
    | otherwise         = a : mergeRow (b:xs)

-- Rotate the grid to be able to do vertical moving/merging
-- e.g. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
-- becomes [0,4,8,12,1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15]
rotate :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotate grid = [ grid !! (a + 4 * b) | a <- [0..3], b <- [0..3] ]

data Move = MoveLeft | MoveRight | MoveUp | MoveDown
    deriving (Show)

allMoves :: [Move]
allMoves = [MoveLeft, MoveRight, MoveUp, MoveDown]

-- Use the definitions above to do the moves
doMove :: Move -> [Int] -> [Int]
doMove _ []             = []
doMove MoveLeft grid    = mergeRow (moveRow (take 4 grid)) ++ doMove MoveLeft (drop 4 grid) 
doMove MoveRight grid   = reverse (doMove MoveLeft (reverse grid))
doMove MoveUp grid      = rotate (doMove MoveLeft (rotate grid))
doMove MoveDown grid    = reverse (doMove MoveUp (reverse grid))

-- Take a turn, i.e. make a move and add a tile
-- Return Nothing if the move is not legal
takeTurn :: Move -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
takeTurn move grid
    | movedGrid == grid = Nothing
    | otherwise         = Just $ addTile 0 movedGrid
    where movedGrid = doMove move grid

-- Return the best move
-- Will throw an error if there are no valid moves
bestMove :: Int -> [Int] -> Move
bestMove depth grid     = snd bestValueMove
    where 
        valueMoves      = [ (value, move) |
                            move    <- allMoves,
                            newGrid <- [ takeTurn move grid ],
                            value   <- [ gridValue depth (fromJust newGrid) ],
                            newGrid /= Nothing ]
        bestValueMove   = maximumBy (comparing fst) valueMoves

-- <<< I decided not to return Nothing on a dead end, because then we can no longer
-- distinguish dead ends at different depths from eachother. >>>
--
-- Return the value of the grid,
-- + 1 for each depth traversed
-- -100 if a Game Over position is reached
gridValue :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
gridValue depth grid
    | depth == 0        = length $ filter (==0) grid
    | values == []      = -100
    | otherwise         = maximum values
    where
        values          = [ value | 
                            move    <- allMoves,
                            newGrid <- [ takeTurn move grid ],
                            value   <- [ gridValue (depth-1) (fromJust newGrid) + 1],
                            newGrid /= Nothing ]

gameOver :: [Int] -> Bool
gameOver grid       = all (==Nothing) ([ takeTurn move grid | move <- allMoves ])

-- Take turns and prints the result of each move to the console until no more moves are possible
-- n counts the moves
-- Should normally be called with n=0
takeTurns :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO()
takeTurns isVerbose depth n grid = do
    when (isVerbose || isGameOver)      $ putStrLn $ gridToString grid ++ "\n# " ++ (show n)
    when (isVerbose && not isGameOver)  $ putStrLn $ (show move)
    when (not isGameOver)               $ takeTurns isVerbose depth (n+1) newGrid
    where
        isGameOver  = gameOver grid
        move        = bestMove depth grid
        newGrid     = fromJust $ takeTurn move grid

-- Solves at depth and only prints # of moves and final grid
solveSilent :: Int -> IO()
solveSilent depth = takeTurns False depth 0 (addTile 0 emptyGrid)

-- Solves at depth and prints all boards and moves
solve :: Int -> IO()
solve depth = takeTurns True depth 0 (addTile 0 emptyGrid)

-- Solve and time the solver for multiple depth settings from start to end
solveDepths :: Int -> Int -> IO()
solveDepths start end
    | start <= end = do
            startTime <- getCurrentTime
            solveSilent start
            stopTime <- getCurrentTime
            putStrLn $ "Depth " ++ (show start) ++ " done in " ++ (show $ diffUTCTime stopTime startTime)
            solveDepths (start+1) end
    | otherwise = putStrLn "-"

main = solveDepths 1 3
```

Answer (score 4):

I am unfortunately no performance guru, but will take a stab at this as I repeatedly had to make programs faster, and there are no answer yet.

A nitpick : I would have used a type synonym for `Grid` and `Row` :

```
type Grid = [Int]
type Row = [Int]
addTile :: Int -> Grid -> Grid
moveRow :: Row -> Row
```

This doesn't help too much here, but might make things more obvious in the long run.

Now, considering performance, the choice of a list of integer will make your program hard to optimize. Functions such as this will be really slow :

```
rotate grid = [ grid !! (a + 4 * b) | a <- [0..3], b <- [0..3] ]
```

As lists are linked lists, and indexing will traverse all previous elements. Profiling shows that this is the most time consuming function.

I would suggest one or a combination of the following solutions.

## Using the `ST` monad

The ST monad is a strict state monad. It is pretty useful for encapsulating value-mutating algorithms in referentially transparent functions. Basically, you would write algorithms the way you would in C, and the resulting code should be quite efficient. The `STArray` type might be a good candidate.

## Using a library known for its performance

A library such as `repa` or `vector`, both are known to be able to generate crazy fast code when the right rewrite rules fire. `repa` is probably overkill, and hard to understand. You can alter vectors in the `ST` monad too.

## Change your representation

The `doMove` function takes most of the time. It has an implementation for a single case (`MoveLeft`), and all other cases rotate the board, run a `MoveLeft`, and rotate it back. It might be possible to either have specialized implementations for each case, or, perhaps better, to use function composition / modification to skip the rotate / rotate back operations.